# Short way to convert a string or character to a new one in java

Tags: java, string, bash, char, tr

I am trying to convert characters in a string into a new character.  Essentially it would convert ATCG into TAGC.  Is there a shorter way of doing this than writing a for loop and checking each character such as the tr command in bash?

Comment: Give a minimal verifiable example of what you're doing so we can help you. Read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: Depends, can you define the pattern **regularly**?

Comment: You'd have to have a `Map` declaring keys and values. Then loop or stream the characters, do the conversion, and collect to String. For people unclear what `tr` is, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tr_(Unix)

Comment: @ElliottFrisch seems like base paring in DNA. In short: yes. Substitute all `'A'`'s with `'T'`'s (and vice-versa) and all `'C'`'s with `'G'`'s (and vice-versa). [idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/)

Comment: @Turing85 I considered that, it could also be swap each adjacent pair of characters (in this example).

Answer (score 0):

@ifly6's comment already sketched the way to go:

A `Map` defines the conversion rules for single characters.
The `String` transformation is done by streaming the characters,
doing the conversion for each character (using the `Map`),
and collecting them to a `String`.

```
public class Main {

    private static Map<Character, Character> charMap = new HashMap<>();

    static {
        charMap.put('A', 'T');
        charMap.put('T', 'A');
        charMap.put('C', 'G');
        charMap.put('G', 'C');
    }

    public static String transform(String s) {
        return s.chars()                               // IntStream
                .mapToObj(c -> charMap.get((char) c))  // Stream<Character>
                .map(Object::toString)                 // Stream<String>
                .collect(Collectors.joining());        // String
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(transform("ATTCGAGC"));     // prints "TAAGCTCG"
    }
}
```

You will notice that (at least for newbies) streams are much harder
to understand than conventional `for` loops.

I recommend to read about [Java 8 streams](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/ma14-java-se-8-streams-2177646.html)
and the Javadocs of the methods used in the code above.